# How to select specific div on click in *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have this in my template:

```
 <div class="ui-g" *ngFor="let product of products;let i=index" (change)="sum(i)" (click)="selectItemForDelete(product)" [ngClass]="{'selected':products[i] == i}">
</div>
```

What i want is to add class `selected` on clicked div. Any suggestion how can i do that?

This is my method on click:

```
 selectItemForDelete(item): void {
        if (this.selected.indexOf(item) === -1) this.selected.push(item);
        else this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code of `selectItemForDelete(product)`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ts
[ngClass]="{'selected':products[i] == i}"
```

should be

```ts
[ngClass]="{'selected':selected.includes(product)}"
```

I think a more efficient way would be to create a 2nd array of the size of `products`.

```ts
constructor() { // ngOnInit(), ...
  this.products = someValue; // whereever `products` is initialized
  this.selected = this.products.map((p) => false);
}

selectItemForDelete(idx:number): void {
  selected[idx] = !selected[idx];
}
```

with

```ts
<div class="ui-g" 
    *ngFor="let product of products;let i=index" 
    (change)="sum(i)" 
    (click)="selectItemForDelete(idx)" 
    [ngClass]="{'selected':selected[i]}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. Your Html

   ```
    <div [class]="divClass" *ngFor="let product of products;let i=index" (change)="sum(i)" (click)="selectItemForDelete(product)" [ngClass]="{'selected':products[i] == i}">
   ```
2. Under **OnInit()** in your component.

   ```
   ngOnInit(){ this.divClass="ui-g"}
   ```
3. **On click of div - change value of divclass**

   ```
   selectItemForDelete(product){this.divClass="selected";}
   ```

Thats it.

Comment: why do i need on init this.divClass="ui-g" ?

Comment: @None That's coz Initially you wish to have ui-g class for your div.